# Using command-line to read and display file names in an entire directory

Tags: java, batch-file

So, I'm using command-line to create a small program (named MineRunner), and I'm rewriting the engine.  Basically, I need the program to read all the files in a directory (specifically .jar files) and echo the name of the file (eg example.jar, would echo example, and so on and so forth)

Except.. it gets a bit more complicated.
Each file is in it's own directory. Sorta. 
The directory tree is listed as:

```
MineRunner 2.0\Data\ServerFiles\
```

and under the ServerFiles there would be multiple folders for each starter.

```
MineRunner 2.0\Data\ServerFiles\Forge1710
MineRunner 2.0\Data\ServerFiles\Minecraft1710
MineRunner 2.0\Data\ServerFiles\Forge164
```

Would it be possible to just read every .jar file in every subdirectory of "ServerFiles"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir /b /s "C:\MineRunner 2.0\Data\ServerFiles\*.jar`

`/b` returns just the file names (delete this part if you need the full path)

`/s` searches recursively, so it looks through every folder inside ServerFiles for .jar files

Answer (score 0):

The following link looks like a hopeful starting point (not the only one, but ...):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html